# Dynamic formatting Excel column chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I've got this inventory document with the item name and the amount we have on stock. I made a column chart to indicate the current stock. However, when a certain item reached a certain threshold (lets say 5 pieces) I want the column  itself change to the color red. How can I do this automatically (i.e. not manually)

For visualization purpose:
[image]

Comment: have a look e.g. [here](http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/341-creating-an-excel-chart-with-conditional-formatting) or [here](https://alesandrab.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/create-charts-with-conditional-formatting/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create two columns showing "Inventory >= 5" and "Inventory < 5".
Create a "Stacked Column" chart showing "Item", "Inventory >= 5" and "Inventory < 5", writing zero if the condition is not met.

```
=IF(B2>=5,B2,0)  
=IF(B2<5,B2,0)
```

Color "Inventory >= 5" blue and "Inventory < 5" red.

**Figures:**
**Final Spreadsheet**
[image: Final Spreadsheet]

**Stacked Column**
[image: Stacked Column]

**Chart Source Data**
[image: Chart Source Data]

Comment: Good solution-but I'd recommend a minor change.  Instead of returning 0, I'd return NA().  That way you can differentiate between no value and a 0 value.